# Shell Script to make Centos Backup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos5

I read in a tutorial that I could use the following command to make a full backup of my CENTOS system:

```
tar cvpzf /backups/backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backups --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys --exclude=/boot/grub --exclude=/etc/fstab --exclude=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ --exclude=/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /
```

That works great for me in the command line. I have tested it and the recovery went well. I would like to be able for this to happen automatically each night, but when I try to do it in a bash script it gives me some error messages. I know how to make a cron job to execute a shell script, but this code is not working to make the backup:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Generic Server Backup With tar
SERVER=`uname -n`
echo "Starting backup for $SERVER..."
tar cvpzf /home/backups/backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backups --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys --exclude=/boot/grub --exclude=/etc/fstab --exclude=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ --exclude=/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /
echo "Done."
```

Anyone out there know what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix it?

The error messages:

```
  sh bu.sh
...rting backup for juice.myserver.com
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /\r: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
Done.
```

Comment: Showing exact error would be a good idea so that we can help.

Comment: Edited to include exact error messages

Comment: One issue to consider with cron is what user the script is run as.  Does the cron user have sufficient permissions?  Are you perhaps testing it under sudo, but then cron'ing it as yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be some issue related to CR (Carriage Return) at the end of the tar command.

After the excludes there's a separate slash (/) which is obviously the path which is going to be backupped. The problem is that tar considers it as /\r and it obviously does not exist.

Recommendation is to try to use some utility like `dos2unix` or using some command like this `tr -d '\r' < bu.sh > newbu.sh` to remove it.

After that, it should work correctly.